# How do I calculate index position of first <w:p> element based on its child attribute value in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

This is my XML Document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">

<w:body>

    <w:p> <!-- index 0 -->
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
        </w:pPr>

        <w:r>
            <w:t>
                 Paragraph1
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>

    <w:p> <!-- index 1 -->
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="TOC1"/>
        </w:pPr>

        <w:r>
            <w:t>
                 TOC1
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>

    <w:p>  <!-- index 2 -->
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="TOC2"/>
        </w:pPr>

        <w:r>
            <w:t>
                 TOC2
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p> <!-- index 3 -->
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="TOC3"/>
        </w:pPr>

        <w:r>
            <w:t>
                 TOC3
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p> <!-- index 4 -->
        <w:pPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>
                 Paragraph2
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>

    <w:p> <!-- index 5 -->
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
        </w:pPr>

        <w:r>
            <w:t>
                 Paragraph3
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>

</w:body>
</w:document>
```

So, Now i want to calculate following two things

1.Count starting index position of element that having `<w:pStyle>` value starting   with "TOC".Here it starting in first`<w:p>` element(Assume index starting from '0').so, i want following output

2.Total number of that having `<w:pStyle>` value starting   with "TOC".I have count this by following expression.So, Please Guide me to get first one...

```
<xsl:attribute name="totalTOC">
   <xsl:value-of select="count(//w:body/w:p[w:pPr[w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val,'TOC')]]])"/>
<xsl:attribute>
```

My Required output is:

```
<Document>
<TOC startIndex="1" totalTOC="3"/>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `preceding-sibling` axis as such:

`count(//w:body/w:p[w:pPr[w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val,'TOC')]]][1]/preceding-sibling::*)`.

This will select the first element that meets your criteria and return the count of its preceding siblings (the current index). For a one-based index, simply add 1.